# working with command hp-plugin for printer

Tags: 12.04, package-management, hp, qt3

I am having a scanner/printer which needs hp-plugin,
it is installed,some how I have forgotten what went wrong during installation
 because when I try to run

```
sudo hp-plugin
```

I get following error

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.12.2)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

warning: Qt/PyQt 4 initialization failed.
error: hp-plugin requires GUI support (try running with --qt3). Try using interactive (-i) mode.
```

when I am running with

```
sudo hp-plugin --qt3
```

I get error

```
error: option --qt3 not recognized
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` or `sudo apt-get install python-qt4`.