# How do I install HP P1102W printer driver

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, hp

Trying to install drivers for a HP P1100W on Ubuntu 12.04.

The printer was recognized as soon as I hooked it up.  I'm using the USB cable.

I followed the directions of this question 
[working with command hp-plugin for printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363961/working-with-command-hp-plugin-for-printer)

and I get the message that I now need the "HP-Plugin.

Also, how do I get rid of all the test prints that are still spooled?  There is no clear button.

Answer (score 2):

Solved after much reading...

Go to the [hplip support page](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1102w.html)

Click <kbd>download hplip</kbd>

Go to `Downloads` or wherever it was saved and run the script, for example

```
sh hplip-3.14.10.run
```

(depending on the version - use `ls` to see it in the terminal)

Follow directions in your terminal.